# Is there a way to store cryptographic keys only in software using KeyStore on Android API Level 28?

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, keystore

I am currently comparing different key-storage solutions on Android regarding performance and therefore want to enforce generating and storing a RSA keypair in software only. Is there any way to do so using the Android Keystore with a device running on Android API Level 28 or higher?

I tried using other providers like BC, but they are no longer supported for this API Level. Using an older device is no option due to performance differences in hardware.

I use following code to generate the keypair in the TEE and .setIsStrongBoxSet(true) for using the embedded Secure Element:

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                keyProperties, "AndroidKeyStore");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        keyAlias,
                        keyUsage).setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                        KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(
                                KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                        .setKeySize(2048)
                        .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                        .setIsStrongBoxBacked(false)
                        .build());
        keyPairTeeRSA = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "store in software"?

Comment: Not using the hardware-backed keystore, but rather the sofware-backed keystore. If neither TEE or SE is available, Android stores keys in the software-backed keystore. The method keyInfo.isInsideSecureHardware() then returns false. But Android keystore generates keys by defaut in the TEE, if there is one available.I want to manually deactive  using the TEE - but cannot find any information on how or if it is possible

Comment: Just specify a different keystore type. There are a bunch, and pros and cons for each, but I'd go with PKCS#12 for it's maturity and wide support. When grabbing a KeyPairGenerator, just don't specify a keystore.